# JQuery prevent removing class if first or last child?

Tags: jquery

I have a class 'active' that is constantly being removed and added to other divs. But I don't want it removed if it is applied to a first or last child...

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YuDDK/1/

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
<div class="item active"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#container').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
    var active = $('.active');

    if (delta > 0) {
        if (active.not(":first-child")) {
            active.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        }

    } else {
        if (active.not(":last-child")) {
            active.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        }
    }

    $(this).scrollTo( $('.active'),100);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: This is a different problem, but the scrollTo plugin is triggering errors in console. You should probably address that (or ask a question addressing that) before trying to fix the first/last child issues.

Comment: Hmm, yeah I keep getting "... has no method 'scrollTo'". Edit: I got it working with a different version of scrollTo.min.js

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`active.not(":first-child")` returns a jQuery object which is always `true`, you can use `is` method instead that returns a boolean value.

```
if ( !active.is(":first-child") )
```